# ZF2 when to use getServiceLocator() and when not to

Tags: php, frameworks, zend-framework2, service-locator

I am really confused on when to use getServiceLocator and when not to.
As an example:

```
+ Module
-+ Helloworld
--+ src
---+ Controller
----+ IndexController.php
----+ IndexControllerFactory.php

---+ Service
----+ LogginService.php
----+ GreetingService.php
----+ GreetingServiceFactory.php
```

GreetingServiceFactory.php has the content:

```
<?php
namespace Helloworld\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;


class GreetingServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $greetingService = new GreetingService();

        $greetingService->setEventManager($serviceLocator->get('eventManager'));

        $loggingService = $serviceLocator->get('loggingService');

        $greetingService->getEventManager()->attach('getGreeting', array(
            $loggingService,
            'onGetGreeting'
        ));

        return $greetingService;
    }
}
```

And IndexControllerFactory.php has the content:

```
<?php
namespace Helloworld\Controller;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class IndexControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{

    public function createService (ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $ctr = new IndexController();

        $ctr->setGreetingService($serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('greetingService'));
        return $ctr;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I need $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator() in my ControllerFactory but not in my ServiceFactory. Why? Both use the same interface ServiceLocatorInterface which does not even define the getServiceLocator() method.

module.config.php:

```
'controllers' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Helloworld\Controller\Index' => 'Helloworld\Controller\IndexControllerFactory'
    )
)
,
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'loggingService' => 'Helloworld\Service\LoggingService'
    ),
    'factories' => array(
        'greetingService'=> 'Helloworld\Service\GreetingServiceFactory'
    ),
)
```

I'd appreciate any clarification :)

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The method `getServiceLocator` is defined on the [`AbstractPluginManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php#L142-L150), since it implements the [`ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.php). As Maks3w pointed out, it is not part of the [`ServiceLocatorInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.1/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceLocatorInterface.php), so avoid using it when implementing a service factory.

You can anyway define your factory as closure and still use it:

```
class MyModule
{
    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
                'IndexController' => function (
                    \Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager $pm
                ) {
                    $ctr = new IndexController();

                    $ctr->setGreetingService(
                        $pm
                            ->getServiceLocator()
                            ->get('greetingService')
                    );

                    return $ctr;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

While in this example `$pm` is indeed a `ServiceLocatorInterface` instance, you will still need to get a reference to the "main" service manager to access the `'greetingService'`.

ZF2 uses different service managers or plugin managers for controllers, services, view helpers, controller plugins, etc... That is mainly for type-hinting (look at the interface of the `AbstractPluginManager` to understand how type strictness is achieved) and for security.

In this case, the security issue is disallowing access to services that are not controllers, especially with routes with a dynamic `controller` parameter. That's why controllers are kept in a separate plugin manager.

Since the controller plugin manager is created from the "main" service manager, it also is initialized thanks to the `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`.

To make this more clear, I've added a graph of the relations (does not include the factory and don't take it as valid UML):

[image: Pseudo-UML]

Answer (score 5):

> As you can see, I need $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator() in my ControllerFactory but not in my ServiceFactory. Why?

The controller factory is called by a different service manager instance (the "ControllerLoader") to the main one. This is so that the dispatcher can't result in an arbitrary class being instantiated by the main service manager.

As a result, the controller factory's $serviceLocator is not the one you need when you want to retrieve 'greetingService', as 'greetingService' is registered with the main service manager. To get the main server manager from the controller one, you use getServiceLocator() and you now have an instance of the main service manager from which you can get() 'greeting service'

This is known as 'peering'. i.e.  the "ControllerLoader" service manager (the one configured via the 'controllers' key in the config or getControllerConfiguration() in a Module class) is set up with the main service manager as a peer.

Answer (score 3):

Denitively you shouln't use `getServiceLocator` since that method is not defined in `ServiceLocatorInterface` instead use `get()`

Answer (score 0):

I am offering this up as an alternative that uses the base module.config.php setup

Now I was doing something similar but using something like this.

```
class BaseServices extends AbstractActionController
implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface{
    ...
  public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator){
        if($serviceLocator instanceof ControllerManager){
          $this->service_locator = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();

          $this->entities_service = $this->service_locator
            ->get('entities_service');

          $this->session = new Session(array(
            'entities_service'=>$this->entities_service,
            'service_locator'=>$this->service_locator,
          ));
          return $this;
        }
      }
  }
...
}
```

Now the thing that had stumped me was having to come to the realization that I needed to only use the first service locator that is used during the instantiation of any controller that extends this class...

On instantiation: this class was first getting fed a ControllerManager and then the ServiceManager for the setServiceLocator method.

I only wanted to use the ControllerManger and its method for getting the ServiceManager to then instantiate my factories;

the partial on my module.config.php

```
module.config.php
{
...
'service_manager' =>
  'abstract_factories' => array(
    'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
   ),
  'factories' => array(
       'entities_service' => 'Service\Providers\Entities',
  ),
   'invokables' => array(
     'post'      => 'Service\Controllers\Runtime\Post',
    ),
  ),
}
```

Now I could have used something like the following to filter for the right ServiceLocator... yet I am a fan of using as little boiler plate as necessary...

```
interface AbstractFactoryInterface
{
  public function canCreateServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName);

  public function createServiceWithName(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator, $name, $requestedName);
}
```