# Injecting and using ServiceLocator into an abstract Zend\Form base class

Tags: zend-form, zend-framework2

I have created an abstract form class called `AbstractApplicationForm`. I want the service locator to be injected into it through the `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` to have access to the translator:

```php
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

abstract class AbstractApplicationForm 
    extends Form 
    implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $serviceLocator;
    protected $translator;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }       

    public function getTranslator()
    {
        if (!$this->translator) {
            $this->translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
        }

        return $this->translator;
    }
}
```

My application forms extend this class like following:

```php
namespace Trade\Form;

use Zend\Captcha;
use Zend\Captcha\Image;
use Zend\Form\Element;
use Application\Form\AbstractApplicationForm;

class MemberForm extends AbstractApplicationForm
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        // Add the elements to the form
        $id = new Element\Hidden('id');
        $first_name = new Element\Text('first_name');
        $first_name->setLabel($this->getTranslator('First Name'))
```

In this way, I can use getTranslator to translate labels.

So far so good. In my controller action, I create the form like this:

```php
public function joinAction()
{
    // Create and initialize the member form for join
    $formManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
    $form        = $formManager->get('Trade\Form\MemberForm');
```

the result is a ServiceManager exception:

> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for translator

I don't have anything else defined in `Module.php` or `module.config.php` and I don't think I need to. I have the translator defined in `module.config.php` like this:

```php
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'translation_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type'     => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
```

Which works fine when I get it in the controller:

```php
$sm               = $this->getServiceLocator();
$this->translator = $sm->get('translator');
```

So the translator config is actually correct, but I am unable to retrieve it in my form.
Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually the same problem you can see at [ZF2 when to use getServiceLocator() and when not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911965/zf2-when-to-use-getservicelocator-and-when-not-to/14915156#14915156)

The [`FormElementManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/Form/FormElementManager.php) is an [`AbstractPluginManager`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php), and in the constructor of `AbstractPluginManager`, following [service initializer](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php#L60-L69) is added:

```php
$this->addInitializer(function ($instance) use ($self) {
     if ($instance instanceof ServiceLocatorAwareInterface) {
        $instance->setServiceLocator($self);
    }
});
```

The fact is that `$self`, in this context, refers to the plugin manager itself. This means that any service that implements [`Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/release-2.1.3/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.php) and which is spawned by the plugin manager (in this case the `FormElementManager`), gets the plugin manager itself injected.

The plugin manager is NOT the main service locator (again, see [ZF2 when to use getServiceLocator() and when not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911965/zf2-when-to-use-getservicelocator-and-when-not-to/14915156#14915156)).

The `Zend\Form\FormElementManager` instance was produced by the main service manager when you called:

```php
$formElementManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager');
```

Since `Zend\Form\FormElementManager` implements `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`, it has a reference to the actual "main" service manager.

Therefore, in your form:

```php
$formElementManager = $this->getServiceLocator();

$mainServiceManager = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();

$translator = $mainServiceManager->get('translator');
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in a fieldset, how to use a translator there?

Answer (score 1):

you may have to do `getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator()->get('translator')`

I don't understand why you have to do this sometimes, but it works.

Comment: It may be because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911965/zf2-when-to-use-getservicelocator-and-when-not-to/14915156#14915156 - the form element manager is actually a different service manager from the main one

Comment: Thank you both for the answer and explanation. That did it!

Comment: @PWansch I don't mean to make this answer less valuable (thus my upvote), but i would highly suggest and ask for it, to make Ocramius answer below as accepted, because this will help the community way more.

Comment: Agreed. I accepted Ocramius's answer. This will definitely help the community. There is quite a bit of confusion around ServiceLocator use and this helps out.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same construct with an abstract fieldset class and an concrete fieldset class. Translator is injected in exactly the same way, but when I try to "$this->getTranslator()" in the fieldset, the following exception is thrown:

**Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for translator**

So the SM is unable to find the translator service.
I added (configured) the translator in the following way:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'translator' => 'Zend\I18n\Translator\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        'Navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
        'logger' => function ($sm) {
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $config = $sm->get('Config');

            if ($config['logger']['writer'] == 'ChromePhp'):
                $logger->addWriter(new \Application\Log\Writer\ChromePhp()); else:
                $logger->addWriter('FirePhp');
            endif;
            return $logger;
        }
    ),
),
'translator' => array(
    'locale' => 'de_DE',
    'translation_file_patterns' => array(
        array(
            'type' => 'gettext',
            'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
            'pattern' => '%s.mo',
        ),
    ),
),
```

In my views the translator works perfect.
So at the momemnt I´ve no idea, what to try next. Can you show me how you added the translation service to your application?

EDIT -------------------------
Additional info:
In the **fieldset class**

```
$this->getServiceLocator();
```

get´s me an object of type "Zend\Form\FormElementManager". That´s correct for a form element.

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->getServiceLocator();
```

But this gives me NULL instead of the ServiceLocator-Object...

Thanks,
Michael