# ZF2 getServiceLocator() not found?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I can't for the life of me get $this->getServiceLocator() to work in my controller.  I've read and tried everything.  I'm guessing I'm missing something??  Here is some code.

```
namespace Login\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\Session\Container as SessionContainer;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller;

use Login\Model\UserInfo;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();

        $this->db = $sm->get('db');
    }
    ...
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /product/WishList/module/Login/src/Login/Controller/LoginController.php on line 21
```

Comment: Where is $sm defined?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, I've adjusted it, and updated the error message.

Comment: Try taking a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911965/zf2-when-to-use-getservicelocator-and-when-not-to

Comment: thanks, will read that over.

Comment: It's not available at the `__construct()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To give my comment a little bit more meaning. The ServiceLocator (or rather all ControllerPlugins) are only available at a later point of the livecycle of the Controller.
If you wish you assign a variable that you can easily use throughout your actions, i suggest to either use **Lazy-Getters** or to inject them using the **Factory Pattern**

**Lazy-Getters**

```
class MyController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $db;
    public function getDb() {
        if (!$this->db) {
            $this->db = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db');
        }
        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

**Factory-Pattern**

```
//Module#getControllerConfig()
return array( 'factories' => array(
    'MyController' => function($controllerManager) {
        $serviceManager = $controllerManager->getServiceLocator();
        return new MyController($serviceManager->get('db'));
    }
));

//class MyController
public function __construct(DbInterface $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
}
```

Hope that's understandable ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is besause your Controller isn't implement the interface of ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.You can see the class Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager,in the construct method:

```
public function __construct(ConfigInterface $configuration = null)
{
    parent::__construct($configuration);
    $self = $this;
    $this->addInitializer(function ($instance) use ($self) {
        if ($instance instanceof ServiceLocatorAwareInterface) {
            $instance->setServiceLocator($self);
        }
    });
}
```

so you must implement it if you want use the ServiceLocator,or extend the class Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController it have implementd the ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.

Comment: As you can clearly see, he is extending `AbstractActionController`, however, the `Initializers`, as you can see, are not called on Controllers `__construct()` but rather **after** they have been initialized. Only after that setter-functions are available. Thus, at the time of a controllers `__construct()` there is simply no dependency injected yet and therefore you can't use any ControllerPlugins at that point in time.