# how to specify redirection ZF2 constructor?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am working on login module in my current project. For accessing profile page user must logged in. For that i am checking login status against session in constructor. if user not logged in page should redirect to log in page.

following is psedo code.

```
    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
    class StatisticsController extends AbstractActionController
    {
    // variables ------
        public function __construct()
        {
           if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_email']))
           {
            $this->redirect()->toUrl('/admin');
           }
        }
    }
```

Above code gives following error message

```
Redirect plugin requires event compose a response
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236468/zf2-getservicelocator-not-found#answer-18243035). In short, ControllerPlugins are not available at `__construct()` as they are injected after construction. Use Route-Events and check the Session stuff there. See the Module [BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize) and see how it's done correctly ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are better off doing this in the onDispatch event, either by attaching to the event, or putting the code into the onDispatch method.

You won't have acess to any ServiceLocator / ServiceManager in the contructor as they are injected after the class is instantiated.

SomeBaseController.php

```
/**
 * Override, check for login etc
 * 
 * @param \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e
 */
public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e) 
{
    if( ! /** SOME CONDITION **/) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
    }

    return parent::onDispatch($e);
}
```